# DATE interval Function gives error in sql

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am running simple query for DATE INTERVAL in my Redshift but it is giving an error for `MONTH`.

My query is as below:

```
select x,y, (x+y), DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL +1 MONTH) AS TIMEHERE from calc;
```

or

```
select x,y, (x+y), DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS TIMEHERE from calc;
```

it gives me an error like

`Error: near line 6: near "MONTH": syntax error`

I cannot figure out what the error is.

Comment: @Strawberry, i have edited my question... i need DATE_ADD func

Comment: Are you using Redshift or MySQL?

Comment: @Strawberry, Sir it produced error...thats why i ask here... else why i will ask.

Comment: @GMB i am using Redshift

Answer (score 0):

In redshift, you can add 1 month to the current date as follows:

```
dateadd(month, 1, getdate())
```

Or, if you don't want the time component:

```
dateadd(month, 1, current_date)
```

You can also do:

```
getdate() + interval '1 month'
```

Or:

```
current_date + interval '1 month'
```

As far as concerns there is no `date_add()` function in Redshift. In MySQL, however, you can do:

```
date_add(now(), interval 1 month)
```

Answer (score 0):

Redshift -- like Postgres -- [wants single quotes around the `interval` literal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_interval_literals.html).  So:

```
now() + interval '1 month'
```

Or because the time component is probably irrelevant:

```
current_date + interval '1 month'
```